# my add form is not showing

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing Zend Framework App.

In my indexcontroller view views/scripts/index/index.phtml

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index',
'action'=>'add'));?>">Add new album</a></p>
```

in my browser is is outputting me only url path so it is not going to the add action.
Here it is my add action in IndexController.php

```
 public function addAction()
    {
        // action body
        $form = new Application_Form_User();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $artist = $form->getValue('artist');
                $title = $form->getValue('title');
                $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
                $albums->addUser($artist, $title);
                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else { 
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my add.phtml is

```
<?php
$this->title = "Add new album";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
echo $this->form ;
?>
```

why it is not going to add action. please suggest 
**Edit More Info**

and i am using this pdf to build the app http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

In page No. 9 
I am not getting where to put this line and is these lines are necessary or not ?

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath('/path/to/scripts');
echo $view->render('script.php');
```

and i haven't set the layout and CSS .but my listing from Database is coming but my add Dction is not working ? Please suggest why

Comment: do you want to see the form where you have this? <p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index',
'action'=>'add'));?>">Add new album</a></p>

Comment: Have you got any custom added Routes?

Comment: What is the correct URL that does take you to the `add` view? What does `$this->url(...)` output in your `index` view? Are you sure it's the correct address?

Comment: And what happens when you don't use url helper, but use this: <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/index/add">Add new album</a>

Comment: @all updated the question please check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added the  following lines in the Bootstrap.php
Because before i was trying to build REST API .

```
#$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController);
        # $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('default', $restRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting in your bootstrap or anywhere for that matter:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Or check your php error logs and post here what error message you got

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfull if you could give us your routing initialisation code (inside your Boostrap.php or application.ini).

At first look, it could be an url assemble contextual misuse.

The Zend_View_Helper_Url is route-contextual, aka its using the last route registered. So if you're on a page that uses a user-defined static route and not the default route, the helper will assemble the url with the user-defined route.

Try defining a route name in your view helper, like this (I assumed it's the default route) :

```
echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'), 'default');
```